# Google maps api GPS application unfortunally stopped

Tags: java, google-maps, android-studio, google-play-services, android-gps

I have application in Android Studio, that shows Google Map using Google Play Services. Application is written for Android 4.0.3. I have generated API key for Google Maps and placed it in google_maps_api.xml file according to [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start). Also I added entry for Google API key and permissions for GPS (to use location), Google Services and network in Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="vkalashnykov.org.mapygoogle">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Also I added code for activity:

```
package vkalashnykov.org.mapygoogle;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;

private static final int LOCATION_MIN_TIME = 30 * 10;
private static final int LOCATION_MIN_DISTANCE = 1;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private Location currentLocation;
public static final String FIXED = "FIXED";
double szerokosc_g; // latitude
double dlugosc_g; // longitude



static final Integer LOCATION = 0x1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {


                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION);

            } else {
                //Metoda requestPermissions jest wywoływana aby uzytkownik mógł podjąć decyzję o nadaniu uprawnien
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION);
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, " " + Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION + " uprawnienia zostały przyznane.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, " " + Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION + "Uprawnienia nie zostały nadane", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Wersja SDK systemu Android :  " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Wersja SDK systemu Android :  " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);



    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    { return; }
    szerokosc_g = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).getLatitude();
    dlugosc_g = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).getLongitude();
    LatLng pozycja = new LatLng(szerokosc_g,dlugosc_g); //adding position
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pozycja).title("Pozycja"));

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(pozycja));
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this, new String[] {  android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION  },
                LOCATION );
    }
    else
    {            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_MIN_TIME, LOCATION_MIN_DISTANCE, this);
        Location gpsLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (gpsLocation != null) {
            currentLocation = gpsLocation;
        } else {
            Location networkLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (networkLocation != null) {
                currentLocation = networkLocation;
            } else {
                currentLocation = new Location(FIXED);
                currentLocation.setAltitude(1);
                currentLocation.setLatitude(43.296482);
                currentLocation.setLongitude(5.36978);
            }

            onLocationChanged(currentLocation);
        }
    }
}




@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    szerokosc_g = location.getLatitude();
    dlugosc_g = location.getLongitude();

    LatLng pozycja = new LatLng(szerokosc_g, dlugosc_g);
    mMap.clear();
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pozycja).title("Pozycja"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(pozycja));

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
}
```

But all I get when run application is unexpected error: "Unfortunally application stopped." What is wrong or how I can check what is wrong with appplcation (on Android Studio there is no any message or logs about error)?

Comment: post the logcat details

Comment: How can I obtain it if I run application on phone?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html and connect your device to your development machine